# One static height div and 2 flexible height divs inside container

Tags: html, position, height

I'm creating a small chat for my site.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="user"></div>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <div id="chatform"></div>
</div>
```

What my end result should look like is something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/XXHTC/2/

This is pretty easy when I know the height of the user div. However, the user div does not have a known height, it expands and shrinks as users log on and off.

The chatform at the bottom has a known height, so I can set position absolute and bottom: "height of chatform div" to it's height so the chat does not overlap it.

How can i set the "top" value of chat relative to the user div as it expands/shrinks.
Don't want the user div to hide anything in the chat div.

Comment: Is using javascript an option?

Comment: Yeah, javascript is fine. I gues I could calculate the height of the user div somehow and set the top value of chat to that maybe.

Comment: Worked like a charm with jQuery :)
$(document).ready(function() { userOnline = $("#user").outerHeight(); $("#chat").css("top", userOnline); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to determine the height of `div#user` and then set the top position of `div#chat` equal to that height.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XXHTC/4/)

Comment: Ye. got it working :) http://jsfiddle.net/XXHTC/5/ (Remove the commented in html to see the change)